# AWS EC2 + Rails + Capistrano: Where should I put my .pem file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just opened a new EC2 instance using Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to set up my Ruby on Rails + Ubuntu + Apache + Passenger + Capistrano environment.

I'm working on a team and I want multiple people to be able to deploy. Would it be unsafe or bad in any way if I put the `mypem.pem` file in `Rails.root/config/`? Or should every one who deploys just `ssh-add mypem.pem`? We do have a private github repo.

Comment: Checking in passwords/keys seems like a pretty bad idea, even if the repo is private.  For instance, a team member forks the repo and then it's public.  Is there a reason you don't want to just pass around the file on USB or something similar amongst your team?

Comment: Yeh I think so too. I was just looking for suggestions. So does that mean all of us have to have the .pem file in the same place in our respective machines?

Comment: I use pem only the first time, then I am adding my ssh key and login without using it. I think the common solution is to create a deploy user and add their ssh keys on the server, inside the /home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys and then they can ssh without password and do a deploy.